# Get an array with one property from an array of objects in ES6

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
[
  {foo: 1, bar: 2},
  {foo: 3, bar: 4}
]
```

What's the most concise and ES6-way of getting an array of only the `foo` values?

Expected result would be:

```
[1, 3]
```

Comment: `data.map(({foo}) => foo);`

Comment: Please use the search :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to loop through the items.

Simply put:

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.
>
> - [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

The method allows to call the provided callback function once for each element of the array. It creates a new array made of the mapped elements.
You can pass both the `element` and `index` as arguments of the callback. The latter is optional (when you don't need it in the callback).

It's a clean way of accessing objects in JavaScript. Here is the code:

```js
let array = [
  {foo: 1, bar: 2},
  {foo: 3, bar: 4}
]

console.log(array.map( e => e.foo ))
```

Answer (score 2):

The Array.prototype.map method is suitable for mapping/transforming one array into another array of the same size. You pass in a function which transforms from one element in the array to a new one. As of 2018 it is considered "modern" to use the so called fat arrow syntax to define an anonymous function for the transformation:

```
const x = [{foo: 1, bar: 2}, {foo: 3, bar: 4}]
x.map(entry => entry.foo)
```

It is also considered "modern" to try to avoid the writing of `for` loops.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [destructuring <strike>assignment</strike>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and return this property by using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var objects = [{ foo: 1, bar: 2 }, { foo: 3, bar: 4 }],
    array = objects.map(({ foo }) => foo);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding lipp's answer:

```
const x = [{foo: 1, bar: 2}, {foo: 3, bar: 4}];
var y = x.map(entry => entry.foo);
```

In the first line, an array of objects is created.
The second line uses a minified lambda expression to return an array of foo attributes from the x array and assign it to y.

Comment: This does not answer the question though

Comment: the result is `[[1, 3]]`.

Comment: lipp's answer was completely correct

Comment: Yes. I was pushing an array inside another. Fixed now.